# PHP script to salesforce

Tags: integration, website-integration

I am integrating sales force with an external website.

The developer at the external end will push the data into sales force.
and it will be in P.H.P script format.

Then how will I get that data into sales force.
can I use it directly or do I need to de serialize or write a code to get that data into sales force.

The data he will send is related to accounts and contacts.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce provides [**PHP Force.com toolkit SDK**](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit) which can be used to interact with Salesforce without any custom code on Salesforce side. It is very easy. So If he wants to insert data related to Account and Contact he can use below sample code.

```
<?php
define("SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR", "../../soapclient");
require_once (SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforcePartnerClient.php');
require_once (SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforceHeaderOptions.php');
require_once ('../userAuth.php');

try {
  $mySforceConnection = new SforcePartnerClient();
  $mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/partner.wsdl.xml');
  $mylogin = $mySforceConnection->login($USERNAME, $PASSWORD);

  $fields = array (
    'FirstName' => 'John',
    'LastName' => 'Smith',
    'Phone' => '510-555-5555',
    'BirthDate' => '1950-01-01'
  );

  $sObject = new SObject();
  $sObject->fields = $fields;
  $sObject->type = 'Contact';

  $sObject2 = new SObject();
  $sObject2->fields = $fields;
  $sObject2->type = 'Contact';

  echo "**** Creating the following:\r\n";
  $createResponse = $mySforceConnection->create(array($sObject, $sObject2));

  print_r($createResponse);
}

?>
```

You can check other [sample code](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Samples) here. You not only insert the data you can perform n number of supported operations.